# How to convert haxe files to C# library or source files

Tags: compilation, haxe

Hi i need to convert(or maybe compile?) some haxe files to C# source file or library project.
i don't have Main file and these source files are importing each other(they are depend to each other).
how can i convert these files to C#.

Comment: https://code.haxe.org/category/compilation/compiling-libraries-without-main-class.html

Comment: thank you sir. it's working!

Comment: one little question. is there a way to specify the version of dot net? for now it converts to dot net version 2 @Gama11

Comment: Use `-D net-ver=35` or alike ([documentation](https://haxe.org/manual/target-cs-external-libraries.html))